# What is the grade of the hadith about repentance of the man who killed 100 people?

Tags: hadith, source-identification

> Abu Sa'id Al-Khudri (May Allah be pleased with him) reported:
>
> Prophet of Allah (ﷺ) said: "There was a man from among a nation before
> you who killed ninety-nine people and then made an inquiry about the
> most learned person on the earth. He was directed to a monk. He came
> to him and told him that he had killed ninety-nine people and asked
> him if there was any chance for his repentance to be accepted. He
> replied in the negative and the man killed him also completing one
> hundred.
>
> He then asked about the most learned man in the earth. He was directed
> to a scholar. He told him that he had killed one hundred people and
> asked him if there was any chance for his repentance to be accepted.
> He replied in the affirmative and asked, 'Who stands between you and
> repentance? Go to such and such land; there (you will find) people
> devoted to prayer and worship of Allah, join them in worship, and do
> not come back to your land because it is an evil place.'
>
> So he went away and hardly had he covered half the distance when death
> overtook him; and there was a dispute between the angels of mercy and
> the angels of torment. The angels of mercy pleaded, 'This man has come
> with a repenting heart to Allah,' and the angels of punishment argued,
> 'He never did a virtuous deed in his life.' Then there appeared
> another angel in the form of a human being and the contending angels
> agreed to make him arbiter between them.
>
> He said, 'Measure the distance between the two lands. He will be
> considered belonging to the land to which he is nearer.' They measured
> and found him closer to the land (land of piety) where he intended to
> go, and so the angels of mercy collected his soul".
>
> [Al-Bukhari and Muslim].
>
> In another version: "He was found to be nearer to the locality of the
> pious by a cubit and was thus included among them". Another version
> says: "Allah commanded (the land which he wanted to leave) to move
> away and commanded the other land (his destination) to draw nearer and
> then He said: "Now measure the distance between them.' It was found
> that he was nearer to his goal by a hand's span and was thus
> forgiven". It is also narrated that he drew closer by a slight
> movement on his chest.
>
> Arabic/English book reference  : [Book 1, Hadith 20](http://sunnah.com/riyadussaliheen/1/20)

I quoted it from [Sunnah.com](http://sunnah.com/riyadussaliheen/1/20) » Riyad as-Salihin » The Book of Miscellany. It says [Al-Bukhari and Muslim] but doesn't provide any information regarding its grade. I searched Google but couldn't find it on Bukhari or Muslim.

My questions are,

- What is it's grade?
- Is it a sahih hadith?
- Is it reported in Bukhari and Muslim?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The story *is* narrated through both Bukhari and Muslim as claimed, with variations in exact wording:

- [Sahih Muslim 2766a](http://www.sunnah.com/muslim/50/54) (the main narration quoted by OP)
- [Sahih Muslim 2766b](http://www.sunnah.com/muslim/50/55) (the first "another version")
- [Sahih al-Bukhari 3470](http://www.sunnah.com/bukhari/60/137) (the second "another version")

All three of these narrations would be considered *sahih* (authentic) by Sunni Muslims.

Comment: Just as a comment the 2nd Version from Sahih Muslim has a "better" narrator chain (all thrusworthy most even of a high level) and the 2nd narration of Muslim and the version of al-Bukhari have a common narrator "Sho'ba" (in the middle of the chain) while most of the narrators of the version of al-Bukahri are the same as in the first version of Muslim.